# Issue with groovy response assertion script in jmeter

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I want to write a code for Response assertion using groovy script , for  the Response data like this:

```
[
    {
        "fieldId":"947bb60f",
        "id":"e7b8ad2b",
        "name":"field",
    }
]
```

Tried using the below groovy script for which i am getting error(failure message).

```
if (!jsonResponse.keySet().containsAll(["fieldId","id","name"] )) {
         failureMessage += "The json response body has wrong structure or error msg.\n\n";

}
```

The same script working fine with the single tree structure as below. Appreciate your help on this with groovy script .

```
[

  "fieldId":"947bb60f",
  "id":"e7b8ad2b",
  "name":"field",

]
```

Comment: `jsonResponse[ 0 ]........` should do the trick

Comment: You have a list with maps.  your check there is written for a map.  you have to iterate the list and do your check inside that iteration (e.g. use `for` or `each`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you are getting a list of items returned (containing a single item)

Assuming you never expect more than one item, you can check the size of it with:

```
if (jsonResponse.size() != 1) {
     failureMessage += "Expected one item, got ${jsonResponse.size()}.\n\n";
}
```

Then, you can grab the first element with:

```
def jsonElement = jsonResponse[0]
```

And check the field names with:

```
if (jsonElement.keySet() != ["fieldId","id","name"] as Set) {
     failureMessage += "Unexpected fields in response ${jsonElement.keySet()}.\n\n";
}
```